# Hosting a Django project that uses redis on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, redis, pythonanywhere

I developed an e-commerce site on my local laptop and the project uses `redis` and when I run the project from localhost, it works perfectly using the following
`r = redis.StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST, port=settings.REDIS_PORT, db=settings.REDIS_DB)`:

```
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 1
```

Now, I am trying to deploy the project to python anywhere. I have installed the redis and started the server, changed `localhost` to `myhost.pythonanywhere.com` but when I run visit the site I get the following error:

```
Error 111 connecting to 50.19.109.98:6379. Connection refused.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://myhost.pythonanywhere.com/en/4/black-garbage-t-shirt/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
Error 111 connecting to 50.19.109.98:6379. Connection refused.
Exception Location: /home/dguy/dguy/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis/connection.py in connect, line 436
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/dguy/dguy/venv/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/dguy/dguy/venv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/dguy/dguy/venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/dguy/dguy/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/dguy/dguy',
 '/home/dguy']
Server time:    Wed, 17 Aug 2016 16:10:56 +0100
```

Can someone please help me. what are the right configuration.

Comment: How did you install redis?

Comment: from http://redis.io/download. Unzip the tar.gz file, enter the redis directory and compile Redis using the `make` command as follows: `cd redis-3.2.3
make`
started the server with `src/redis-server`
installed in django venv using `pip install redis==3.2.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis will not work on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: can you please explain? or suggest other places where i could host the project for  testing?

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: our site doesn't support the kind of "long-running" processes you need to keep a redis server running (though we're working to change that).  But if you have a paid account, you can access external redis providers like Redis Labs'.  If you provision your redis instance in Amazon's us-east-1c data center then you'll be right next to our servers, so latency will be minimal.

Comment: Redis Labs advocate here: any us-east instance will do (your us-east-1c and my us-east-1c aren't necessarily the same: https://support.redislabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/202932038-Why-do-you-recommend-mapping-my-availability-zone-on-AWS-)

Comment: How interesting!  I didn't know that.

Comment: @GilesThomas Please Consider adding Redis in pythonanywhere and your site is amazing.my site is hosted there and i now want to implement a chat in my django app but i can't because of the lack of redis in pythonanywhere.

Comment: You can still use a Redis Labs instance with PythonAnywhere, if you have a paid account.